# Enable Enterprise keywords in SharePoint online using Powershell/CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, csom

I'm setting up a Office365 / SharePoint Online portal using Powershell and CSOM and have sorted almost everything out except adding this:

Library Settings -> Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings -> Add an Enterprise Keyword column to this list and enable Keyword synchronization from the UI.

The code im using to add the WikiPage Library is:

```
#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$Username = "username"
$Site = "sitename"
$ListTitle = "WikiPageLib"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredential($Username,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Create List
$ListInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$ListInfo.Title = $ListTitle
$ListInfo.TemplateType = "119"
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.Add($ListInfo)
$List.Description = $ListTitle
$List.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

I have only found C# and on-premise solutions, nothing for SharePoint Online. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found any solution?